# ASP.NET print controls and Microsoft and Dundes Charts in PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I am developing an intranet web application for my company and now I need to add Print Functionality that enables the admin to print some charts (either Microsoft Charts or Dundes) and GridViews in PDF. **So is there any simple way to implement this functionality?**

I tried to use iTextLibrary but it is very difficult to use and customize.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Report Viewer controls? it is not direct printing but it only takes one extra click to export to pdf.